# BBC flash videos don't play in Firefox (Youtube videos do, and all is fine in Chrome)

Tags: 10.10, firefox, youtube, flash

Ubuntu 10.10, 32 bit. Firefox 3.6.14

Why don't BBC videos play in Firefox if Youtube has no problem? Moreover videos play fine in Chrome. Another strange thing: there seem to be two flashplugins in about:plugins

> File: libflashplayer.so Version:
>   Shockwave Flash 10.1 r102
>
> File: libflashplayer.so Version:
>   Shockwave Flash 10.2 r152

But there is only one flashplugin in the plugins directory: `/usr/lib/firefox/plugins/flashplugin-alternative.so` -> `/etc/alternatives/firefox-flashplugin`

```
$ update-alternatives --list firefox-flashplugin /usr/lib/flashplugin-installer/libflashplayer.so
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a recent problem? The BBC have changed some of their flash videos 'format' in the last few days?

Comment: Solved. No idea what the problem was. Just know the symptom -- the presence of two flash plugins. Reinstalled flashplugin from the Ubuntu repo and cleared the Firefox cache and cookies and restarted Firefox. And voilà! videos work. Now about:plugins shows only the 10.2 r152 plugin.

Comment: It could be the way the servers where assigning the mime types. but you say it is working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. No idea what the problem was. Just know the symptom -- the presence of two flash plugins. Reinstalled flashplugin from the Ubuntu repo and cleared the Firefox cache and cookies and restarted Firefox. And voilà! videos work. Now about:plugins shows only the 10.2 r152 plugin.